# trying to increase snae size by for units in my JS snake game

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I'm making a snake game in JavaScript and so far I can move the snake and generate a random food unit on the canvas. I can also eat the food and increment the snakes length by one. However I would like to increase it by four. I used `snake.unshift(newHead);` to add one new head, so my thinking is I just repeat this 4 times. This just makes the snake huge. Can someone please explain why I'm getting this type of result and give me a hint at the solution? Thanks:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
 //add 3 nore heads
 snake.unshift(newHead);
 snake.unshift(newHead);
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
setInterval(draw, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are adding four new heads in every iteration, regardless if the snake eats or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding four new heads in every iteration, regardless if the snake eats or not.

Using your exact code below I have just seperated the eating part out to it's own function (of course this could be improved a lot - but this will give you an idea). The snake grows when it eats, not all the time.

And... just a heads up, you also need to make sure that the food is not placed *on* the snake. It's a cool project, good luck with it.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }

        eat(newHead);
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

function eat(newHead) {
    //add 3 nore heads
 snake.unshift(newHead);
 snake.unshift(newHead);
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
setInterval(draw, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Also were you saying that the eat function could be improved a lot, or just my code in general?

Comment: No problems, well.. regarding the function, here's a hint;  instead of repeating the same line of code multiple times you could create some kind of logic that does that for you. Code can always be improved, one improvement is often to split logic up in appropriate parts. If the entire logic is within your game loop it might be difficult to maintain as it grows.